# Defining setter in factory function using square bracket property access gives TypeScript error

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a factory function that returns an object with a setter and getter. The object represents a predefined pseudo cache that can save data to a property. Here is my example:

```
interface CacheData {
  accessToken: string;
  expiration: number;
}

function cacheFactory(data: CacheData) {
  const cache: CacheData = data;
  return {
    getItem(key: string) {
      return cache[key as keyof CacheData];
    },
    setItem(key: string, value: unknown) {
      cache[key as keyof CacheData] = value; // HERE I GET THE ERROR!
    },
  };
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMKIBYQCJzHZAbwChllEkBnSgFQHsBrCEALmUrClAHMBuU5BAAeAB2BQ8wOq2QgArgFsARtH4BfYsRhyQCMFJDIEmCADFEYOlACeACgAmeOG3QIsufAEoiAhNI5GJi4mHgQAvMiO%20PxkUBBgclCGJGRk3PEAkpAKtkzWbBxcINzeKamx8YmGxm4QANp55JTIeXQwaCFOALoxqWoANAJklJnZuRD57Jw8-cgAbnAANnIQbDoMIHQA7iClQ6k1WA0TTS0TbR21oV3IEQvLEL1kAwJq6kA)

I receive the error `Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'never'.` at `cache[key as keyof CacheData] = value;`

How can I solve this error?

Comment: What were you expecting to happen? If `value` is of `unknown` type and we don't even know which of the properties we're assigning to (hence whether it should be `string` or `number`) that's bound to be unsafe. For type safety you'd need something like https://tsplay.dev/wRlnxm.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've been thinking if this is possible with generics. 
The type of the `value` should be known at the time of typing  invokiation of `setItem`

Comment: [Generics help!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=28&ssc=47&pln=1&pc=1#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)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) here at all. For type safety you want to *already know* whether `key` is a valid key of `CacheData`, then you can use *which key* to determine the appropriate parameter/return type:

```js
function cacheFactory(data: CacheData) {
  const cache: CacheData = data;
  return {
    getItem<K extends keyof CacheData>(key: K): CacheData[K] {
      return cache[key];
    },
    setItem<K extends keyof CacheData>(key: K, value: CacheData[K]): void {
      cache[key] = value;
    },
  };
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mqk6dw)

---

As pointed out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73375886/defining-setter-in-factory-function-using-square-bracket-property-access-gives-t/73376070#comment129581931_73375886) you could also make the type of `data`/`cache` generic, so your `cacheFactory` is more reusable:

```js
function cacheFactory<T>(data: T) {
  const cache: T = data;
  return {
    getItem<K extends keyof T>(key: K): T[K] {
      return cache[key];
    },
    setItem<K extends keyof T>(key: K, value: T[K]): void {
      cache[key] = value;
    },
  };
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mAQn4m)

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can do:

```js
cache[key as keyof CacheData] = (value as never);
```

This will get rid of the error message.

Comment: It does get rid of the message, but at that point you might as well just use `any` everywhere or stop using TypeScript entirely. Lying more to the compiler isn't a solution!

Comment: I know, that is why I said it is a workaround, not a solution :)